# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. For decimal less than 100.00 to NUMERIC(18,2)

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that gives me an error of

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

When I try to run it. I have traced this back to just 3 parameters that cause this. all 3 values are decimal values less than 100 (for example 36.2 or 11.92) they are of datatype decimal. in SQL the data type is `NUMERIC(18, 2)`. They are percentage values taken from a spreadsheet. they are all ran through this method:

```
//Parses Percentages or returns zero if parse fails.
public static decimal PctParseOrZero(string val)
{
    decimal newVal;
    if (val.EndsWith("%"))
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1), out newVal))
        {
            return newVal;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        decimal.TryParse(val, out newVal);
        return newVal;
    }
}
```

When I try to run my stored procedure I get the error above. Why am I getting an arithmetic overflow for values that should obviously fit into `NUMERIC(18, 2)`?

Comment: I'm not seeing the sproc here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't show us your stored procedure, I cannot make sure what you trying to do with the decimal value.

However, please be aware that, when you retrieve the percentage value from excel, for example: **36.9%**, it actually return **0.369**.

Such that, in your example, even excel show the values **36.2%**, but it actually passing **0.392** in your stored procedure, which violate `NUMERIC(18, 2)`

You can try to modify your code from:

```
if (decimal.TryParse(val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1), out newVal))
{
    return newVal;
}
```

to:

```
if (decimal.TryParse(val.Substring(0, val.Length - 1), out newVal))
{
    return newVal * 100;
}
```

Otherwise, you may need to modify your stored procedure to fit this